# What Media Query To Target Android Tablet?

Tags: android, media, tablet

I am using the following media queries. Do any of these target Android Tablets? I am trying to design for Android Tablets ( 7 and 10 inch) both landscape and portrait.

Will these queries handle this or do I need a different target to support Android Tablets?

Desk Top
    @media all and (max-width: 1024px)

Apple iPad
    @media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) 
    @media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)

Mobile
    @media all and (max-width: 767px)
    @media all and (max-width: 600px)
    @media all and (max-width: 480px)

Answer (score 0):

There is another post with lot's of valuable answers which [can be found here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile?rq=1)

One answer states the following queries.:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px) { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```